# How to split string with defining multiple regular expression in clojure?

Tags: string, clojure

I'm new in ***clojure*** programming. I'm learning about splitting a string by defining regular expressions. I'm learning from here https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split

I want to split a string by defining two regular expressions. For example:

```
=> (require '[clojure.string :as str])

=> (str/split "Hello world! Have a nice day" #" ")
;; ["Hello" "world!" "Have" "a" "nice" "day"]

=> (str/split "Hello world!\nHave a nice day" #"\n")
;; ["Hello world!" "Have a nice day"]
```

This is cool. Now I'd like to split a string on every ***space*** & ***newline***.

If the input is **"Hello world!\nHave a nice day"**, The output should be **["Hello" "world!" "Have" "a" "nice" "day"]**

can anyone suggest me, How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would recommend you to use `#"\s+"` as the splitting regex, because `\s` symbol class includes all the whitespace characters (as of java regex they are `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html).

```
user> (clojure.string/split "Hello world! Have  a nice   day\naaa bbb" #"\s+")
["Hello" "world!" "Have" "a" "nice" "day" "aaa" "bbb"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got my answer.